# VB.NET Move Objects using mouse

Tags: vb.net, object, customization

I was thinking about creating a form, where the user can move arround different Objects like textboxes, labels and pictureboxes.  I searched in the Internet for something simmilar, but I could not find the right thing. The code I wrote untill now works fine, but just if I manually assign the object before debugging. Any Idea how I could get the object?

Here´s the code I got untill now:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim cursorposx As Integer
Dim cursorposy As Integer
Dim currentobj As Object

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    cursorposx = e.X
    cursorposy = e.Y
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If Not currentobj = Nothing Then

        Label1.Text = cursorposx

        Label2.Text = cursorposy

        currentobj.Location = New Point(cursorposx, cursorposy)
    End If
End Sub
```

I search for a method to assign the variable "currentObj" the Object while I dobbleclick an object.

Thank you a lot.

Edit:

I will try it out the way LarsTech considered it to me.
+ I will use a List of Objects so I can index them.

Comment: You get the object from the sender parameter in the MouseDown event for each control.

Comment: But Is there a way I could use that without have to define it for each object? Because I wannt give the user a possibility to create child-Objects.

Comment: It would be the simplest way.  You can assign each control the same event handler.

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot. 
I updated my post